# Nodejs, why lines after ASYNC call are not executing?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, asynchronous, async-await, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a AWS Lambda function with Nodejs.

Inside the code I have to call a API, wait for the response and do other things with that data (I haven't still write anything about this)
NOTE: sorry about declaring customerTAX as global, but I prefer to get the lambda function to work with and after, try to return the value from the function isself.

This is the code:

```
'use strict';

var customerTAX;
const https = require('https');
const options = {
      host: 'xxxxxxx.com',
      port: 443,
      path: '/yyyyyyy.json',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/graphql',
      }      
};

exports.handler = async (event) => {

        const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
        const orderId = body.id;
        const customerId = body.customer.id; 
        console.log('ORDER ID: ' + orderId);
        console.log('CUST  ID: ' + customerId);
        const query = `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`;

        //I CAN SEE ALL LOGS OF THIS FUNCTION IN CLOUDWATCH
        await getCustomerTAX(query);  
        //I CAN'T SEE NOTHING BELOW THIS LINE IN AWS CLOUDWATCH

        console.log('CUST TAX: ' + customerTAX);
        if (customerTAX != null) {
            console.log('LETs GO TO SAVE IT')
        } else {
            console.log('NOTAX: No customerTAX');
        }

        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify(event.body),
        };          
        return response;
};

var getCustomerTAX = function(query) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var req = https.request(options, function(res) {  
            res.setEncoding('utf8');
            var bodyRaw = '';
            res.on('readable', function () {
                var chunk = this.read() || '';
                bodyRaw += chunk;
                console.log('getTAX CHUNK (' + Buffer.byteLength(chunk) + ' bytes): ' + chunk);
            });            
            res.on('end', function () {
                const body = JSON.parse(bodyRaw);
                if (body.TAX.value != null) {
                    customerTAX = body.TAX.value;
                } else {
                    customerTAX = null;
                }     
                console.log("getTAX END: " + customerTAX);
                resolve;
                //console.log('body: ' + Buffer.byteLength(body) + ' bytes');
            });
        });
        //handle the possible errors      
        req.on('error', function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR: " + e);
            reject(e);
        });
        //do the request
        req.write(query);
        //finish the request
        req.end();
    });
};
```

Function getCustomerTAX works perfectly, but I don't know why my lambda function is "finished" in this line, and I can't see more console-logs in cloudwatch.

Hope your answer and thanks a lot.

Comment: You have an extra `}` after your return statement, is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, the extra ```}```is a type, sorry. I have just edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters in `getCustomerTax()`, `resolve;` needs to be `resolve();`.

It's a function. You need to call it.

Without calling `resolve()`, the promise is never resolved and thus `await getCustomerTax()` never finishes and the lines after it are never executed.

---

FYI, the [`request-promise` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) will automatically do a lot of what you have in `getCustomerTax()` (make an http request, get the response, handle all possible errors and return a promise that represents the result).

---

**EDIT Jan, 2020 - request() module in maintenance mode**

FYI, the `request` module and its derivatives like [`request-promise`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) are now in maintenance mode and will not be actively developed to add new features.  You can read more about the reasoning [here](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode).  There is a list of alternatives in [this table](https://nodesource.com/blog/express-going-into-maintenance-mode#alternativestorequest) with some discussion of each one.  I have been using [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got) myself and it's built from the beginning to use promises and is simple to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, works perfect. Now I'm a little embarrassed by the question, but thanks a lot. I will try now to go on the work, I hope not to have more question, but thanks a lot to stackoverflow too.

Comment: About request-promise I will have if AWS Lambda function Nodejs layer has it or not. (and I will have to learn how to use it). May be I will go on with this code and after I get manange to run it without any issues I will try to improve it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JuanRangel - The request, request-promise or request-promise-native libraries are very easy to use and simpler than what you're doing.  They support all the same options as `http.get()` since they're just a layer on top of that.  Worth using next time.  They even have an option for parsing the JSON for you.  They literally just change all your code to `return rp(options)` where `const rp = require('request-promise');` and then the return value comes back as the resolved value of the returned promise.